# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object, не могу понять в чем ошибка

Tags: python-3.x

Имеется следующий класс (не уверен что он написан правильно):

```
import random


class BubbleAndQuick:

    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def bubblesort(self):
        lengthOfArray = len(self.array) - 1
        for i in range(lengthOfArray):
            for j in range(lengthOfArray - i):
                if self.array[j] > self.array[j + 1]:
                    self.array[j], self.array[j + 1] = self.array[j + 1], self.array[j]
        return self.array

    def quicksort(self, array):
        if len(self.array) <= 1:
            return self.array
        else:
            q = random.choice(self.array)
        l_nums = [n for n in self.array if n < q]
        e_nums = [q] * self.array.count(q)
        b_nums = [n for n in self.array if n > q]
        return self.quicksort(l_nums) + e_nums + self.quicksort(b_nums)

def main():
    array = [2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 6, 8, 7, 98, 9, 89, 665, 4, 32]
    test = BubbleAndQuick(array)
    print(test.bubblesort())
    print(test.quicksort(array))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 32, 89, 98, 665]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/Документы/sort.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/***/Документы/sort.py", line 31, in main
    print(test.quicksort(array))
  File "/home/***/Документы/sort.py", line 25, in quicksort
    return self.quicksort(l_nums) + e_nums + self.quicksort(b_nums)
  File "/home/***/Документы/sort.py", line 25, in quicksort
    return self.quicksort(l_nums) + e_nums + self.quicksort(b_nums)
  File "/home/***/Документы/sort.py", line 25, in quicksort
    return self.quicksort(l_nums) + e_nums + self.quicksort(b_nums)
  [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
  File "/home/***/Документы/sort.py", line 21, in quicksort
    q = random.choice(self.array)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 259, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 232, in _randbelow
    if type(random) is BuiltinMethod or type(getrandbits) is Method:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

В ООП разбираюсь еще не очень хорошо.

Comment: Отступы в `quicksort` кривые

Comment: @extrn не помогло.

Comment: Текст ошибки понятен?

Comment: Сам алгоритм `quicksort` тоже неправильный: параметр `array` игнорируется, да и не должно его вовсе быть, судя по всему. Пишите/ищите реализацию `quicksort` по месту и/или используйте вспомогательные функции.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том что из quicksort вызывается quicksort и так до бесконечности.
Почему? потому что отписали выше - в quicksort берётся self.array, а не array